# Grab video URL from external URL

Tags: php, jquery, curl, video, cross-domain

I'm trying to access the URL of the video element from an external URL.

That's an example of the url I'm trying to access:
https://www.musical.ly/v/MzA4NTExODI2MDI0MjMzNDgxOTEyMzI.html

file_get_contents and curl return an html code without the video in it, what am I doing wrong?

Any PHP/jQuery solution would be great!

Comment: I'm guessing that you want the video from the above URL? That won't work with `file_get_contents` or `curl` since the video doesn't exist in the HTML, but is loaded through javascript (jpplayer, to be exact) when the page has been loaded.

Comment: this is the row of HTML you need to parse: `<video id="jp_video_0" preload="auto" src="http://res01.musical.ly/reg02/2017/01/08/20/182602423348191232.mp4" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></video>`. This contains the link to the mp4 file.

Comment: You could use regex or directly parse the HTML structure to get the URL. you can than do whatever tou want with that link: embed it in you page or download it.

Comment: but as @MagnusEriksson wrote, the video is loaded through javascript when the page has been loaded. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @LucaAngioloni - That HTML doesn't exist in the default document. It's generated using the jpplayer library (using js) _after_ the page has been loaded so he don't get that when fetching the source.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is there a way to fetch the video after it's loaded?

Comment: It seems like the: `MzA4NTExODI2MDI0MjMzNDgxOTEyMzI`-part of the url is the video key and that they are calling: `https://www.musical.ly/rest/v2/musicals/shareInfo?key=MzA4NTExODI2MDI0MjMzNDgxOTEyMzI` to fetch the video data (including the videoUri) in json format, when building the player. You could do the same?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that'll do! thank you

Comment: I can write it as an answer so you can close this question.

Comment: @user3160630 if the Answer works, then mark it as solved using the `✔` mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `MzA4NTExODI2MDI0MjMzNDgxOTEyMzI`-part of the url is the video key.

They are calling: `https://www.musical.ly/rest/v2/musicals/shareInfo?key=MzA4NT‌​ExODI2MDI0MjMzNDgxOT‌​EyMzI` to fetch the video information in json format.

You could do the same and just use the `videoUri` from the json response?

#### Example

Just for fun, I created an example how to fetch it from the initial URL. This would of course need a bit of validation and such, but it is a working example:

```
<?php
$url      = 'https://www.musical.ly/v/MzA4NTExODI2MDI0MjMzNDgxOTEyMzI.html';

// Extract the url path and explode the segments
$segments = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));

if (isset($segments[2])) {
    // We have the key segment so let's build the URL to fetch the info
    $infoUrl = 'https://www.musical.ly/rest/v2/musicals/shareInfo?key=' . rtrim($segments[2], '.html');
    $info    = file_get_contents($infoUrl);
    $info    = $info ? json_decode($info, true) : null;
}

if (isset($info['result'], $info['result']['videoUri'])) {
    // We have all we need, let's get the video uri
    echo $info['result']['videoUri'];
} else {
    die('No video URI found');
}
```